# "sort -c -k1" compares second field too?

Tags: sorting

"sort" correctly reports these two lines are out of order:

```
> echo "a b\na a" | sort -c 
sort: -:2: disorder: a a
```

How do I tell sort to compare only the first field of each line? I tried:

```
> echo "a b\na a" | sort -c -k1 
sort: -:2: disorder: a a
```

but it failed, as above.

Can I make sort compare the first field of each line only, or must I 
used something like sed to trim the lines before comparing them?

EDIT: I'm using "sort (GNU coreutils) 7.2". I tried using a different field separator but it didn't help:

```
> echo "a b\na a" | sort -k1 -c -t" "
sort: -:2: disorder: a a
```

although I'm pretty sure space is the default separator anyway.

Comment: I think `sort` fields are separate by commas be default. You might have to change the delimiter with `-d` (IIRC).

Comment: It's `-t`, but it makes no difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works as expected:

```
echo "a b\na a" | sort -s -c -k1,1
```

There were two problems with your sort invocation:

- The argument to `-k` is a key definition that specifies a start and end position. If end position is omitted, it defaults to the last field of the line, not the start field. `-k1,1` specifies both, telling `sort` not to include the second field in the comparison.
- `sort` is not stable by default, which means it doesn't guarantee not to disturb the order of lines that compare equal. Quoting the documentation:

> Finally, as a last resort when all keys compare equal, `sort` compares
>   entire lines as if no ordering options other than `--reverse` (`-r`)
>   were specified.  The `--stable` (`-s`) option disables this
>   "last-resort comparison" so that lines in which all fields compare
>   equal are left in their original relative order.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought `-k` is just buggy... but I couldn't spot a flaw in it, except for this resorting, and then it occurred to me to search for "stable" in the info manual. IMNSHO `-s` should be the default when `-k` is in use - who wants a non-stable sort in 2013?